# NGINX - Serving a create-react-app application on one port and my api on another port

Tags: nginx, node.js, pm2

In my application i am using create-react-app and serving my site's frontend on the port 5000 by using "serve -s build" in a node pm2 process. I can get this working by using this configuration for my nginx.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name random.com www.random.net;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/random.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/random.net/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name random.net www.random.net;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

However when i add this part to my configuration it breaks both my standard location and the api endpoint doesnt work. this is another proccess running in another pm2 instance serving my api, i would expect these routes under my api, which is served through express to return json files.

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:9000";
}
```

The end configuration i get is below and it doesnt work.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name random.com www.random.net;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/random.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/random.net/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;



location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:9000";
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name random.net www.random.net;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

It would be great if someone could tell me what im doing wrong and how i could fix it. thanks! :))

Comment: Have you tried to remove quotation from proxy_pass, e.g. write `proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9000;`?

Answer (score 1):

**From comments**

There is problem with quotation in proxy_pass. It should looks like:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```